# Pivotal HAWQ - Centos 7 Installation

Tags: greenplum, hawq

We have small Hadoop cluster. Hadoop  HDP version Installed in it.
**Env:**
VM consist of os : Centos 7

**Facing compatibility issue** : HAWQ compatibility issue as it is not supported for Centos 7 Yet.
Constraint: We already installed Hadoop cluster on Centos 7.

Any help on it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAWQ is not, as of yet, supported on 7.  It is in the backlog of items and should hopefully be done quickly - but if you're looking to test it's capabilities in the near term, I suggest you reinstall with < 7.